# Using UIResponder methods for UIControl views

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrol, uiresponder

I am trying to use `UIControl` as the superclass for a custom `ActionView` , in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol) it says I need to use `beginTracking(..` to track interactions:

> Override the beginTracking(*:with:), continueTracking(*:with:),
> endTracking(_:with:), and cancelTracking(with:) methods to track touch
> events occurring in the control. You can use the tracking information
> to perform additional actions. Always use these methods to track touch
> events instead of the methods that the UIResponder class defines.

More importantly, it stays I should avoid the `UIResponder` methods, e.g.: `touchesBegan(...`.

Well, all subviews of the `UIControl` need to have `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `false` so `beginTracking(..)` is called.

Disabling the interaction of all subviews makes that my custom view cannot have a `UIButton` as subview anymore (or not so easily). Using `touchesBegan(..)` makes that everything works, view works as I want it, `UIButton` subviews are interacted with.

Does someone know why `touchesBegan(..)` should be avoided, what are the downsides?

Comment: Notice that in `beginTracking`, you can return a `Bool` telling the control whether you want to continue tracking this touch or not. If you use `touchesBegan`, the control doesn't get to know that. Also, if your custom control has other `UIControl`s as subviews, I think it should be a `UIView` instead...